# How to know if a .jar built on AMD64 will run flawlessly on ARM?

Tags: java, gradle, java-native-interface, compatibility, portability

I built a `.jar` in docker on the **ARM** architecture and one on **AMD64**.

The two `.jar` files have the identical size, but `vbindiff` says their contents are quite different.

I tested both `.jar` files on my AMD64 computer and the reversed slogan "build anywhere, run once" holds.

My hypothesis is that this has to do with **Java Native Interface (JNI)**. The `.jar` is a Spring Boot Webflux backend. Unfortunately, I don't know if it or any other dependency uses JNI.

I noted that the ARM image has **JDK 17.0.3** installed, while the AMD64 image has **JDK 17.0.2.** But this should not be a problem, since I built both `.jar`s using the **Gradle wrapper**, which specifies the exact toolchain to be downloaded and used to build the project:

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
```

What could be the reason for the difference? Can I assume that either `.jar` can be used on any platform that has a compatible JVM?

**EDIT**: I followed Thomas' advice and used `diff -r` to compare the extracted contents of the `.jar` files. They are identical.

However, `diff` confirms that the `.jar` files themselves are different.

I just learned that the `.jar` format is based on `.zip`, which can use various compression methods, as well as include extra information in file headers, such as 'last modified' or optional OS-specific attributes. Mystery solved.

Comment: The generated byte-code is optimized for the building CPU architecture, but should be executable by other CPU architectures too, though the JVM. Java programs are runable on all machines that are able to run the JVM, as long as your Java programs doesn't use machine- or OS specific stuff.

Comment: @paladin That is incorrect, bytecode targets the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), and it is not optimized for the "building CPU architecture". In fact, javac does hardly any optimization. Most optimization happens at runtime by the JIT compiler if and when the JVM determines it is worthwhile to optimize.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel We are both right. Byte code is optimized for the JVM in use and the used JVM is optimized for the CPU architecure and OS. So byte code is indirectly optimized for CPU architecture and OS. Most major difference in JVM is being a 32bit or 64bit JVM. Which is probably the case in OP scenario (ARM 32bit JVM vs AMD64 64bit JVM).

Comment: You said _"The generated byte-code is optimized for the building CPU architecture"_ and that is not the case. Optimization doesn't happen at build time, it happens at run time.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You wrote "javac does hardly any optimization". Does this mean that the few optimizations that do happen are never architecture-specific?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik The only architecture javac knows about is the JVM. That is the whole point of Java having a virtual machine. Bytecode is the instruction set of the JVM, and it is a JVM *implementation* that does optimization at runtime based on the platform it was build for, and runtime characteristics and CPU features available. If javac does any optimization at all, it is not related to the CPU architecture that is running javac itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the files in the `.jar` using `jar tf myfile.jar`. If the  only contents are `.class` files and the manifest data in `META-INF/`, then chances are good that it's 100% portable. If you see other files like `.so`, `.dll` or `.dylib`, then there is native code in there which might give trouble.

Here's how you can list all the files which might warrant a closer look:

```
jar tf myfile.jar | grep -Pv '^META-INF/|(\.class|/)$'
```

Since you have already built the `.jar`s on two different platforms, you can also extract their contents using `jar xf myfile.jar` and use `diff -r` to compare them recursively. This is a more robust way to detect differences than comparing the archives directly, although I imagine that `.class` files might not be byte-wise identical either even if they're semantically the same.